# Javascript not showing up on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages

I'm new to web development.
I made a website using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and uploaded it to GitHub Pages. My JavaScript doesn't work there.

When running on my localhost, everything works fine, but on GitHub pages the javascript simply does not show up on my HTML page. If you check the IMPORTANTE_LER.md file, there's a youtube video on how it looks on localhost.

My repo: https://github.com/maruan-achkar/N2PAC_NEW

Console errors:

[image]

Comment: Look in the console, there are errors like "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

Comment: how to I look up the GitHub pages console?
I've added ./ to my code but it did not fix it, unfortunally =(

Comment: All I managed to find is this:
build
Node.js 12 actions are deprecated. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: actions/checkout, actions/checkout

Comment: The console is in your browser's developer tools, not GitHub. That should be a routine part of your JavaScript debugging.

Comment: this is what the console shows: https://imgur.com/a/jadqNag

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error for the URL `https://maruan-achkar.github.io/aula06.js`. `src="../aula06.js"` should be `src="./aula06.js"` since it's in the same directory as `index.html`, not the parent directory.

Comment: I tried changing the src to what you said but it did not work =(
../ also doesnt work

Comment: I don't see that change in your repo. It still says `src="../aula06.js"`

Comment: I changed it back as it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Probably the way you included your JS file path breaks in Github Pages because it can't find the file so adding a "./something.js" to your include might fix it.

```
<script src="./something.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: There's no `js` directory, so just `./index.js`

Comment: True, I'm just showing an example. But ill correct my answer anyways. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunally it did not work, I still can't see my javascript on the index.html page =(