# VSCode "Transparent" Folder

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

**Hello! One of my folders is showing up less opaque then the other ones in VSCode, and because of that, it isnt being uploaded to github when I commit.
How can I fix it?**
I don't really know what to google because everything I try doesnt take me to any fixes. Thank you! (the folder isn't hidden on windows, my hidden folders don't show up at all on vscode).[image]

Comment: Its probably an ignored file. Check your .gitignore file. Also, BTW, you should not be checking `node_modules` into version control as a rule so you usually *want* to ignore this folder.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm having problems with my JavaScript so I'm trying everything at this point.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74133755/javascript-not-showing-up-on-github-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @topsail commented, the folder was "ignored" and is easily fixed through the .gitignore file!